# Copy list and append an element in one line

Tags: python

Can this be reduced to a single line (after assigning `a`)?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a[:]
b.append(4)
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The following is probably the simplest:

```
b = a + [4]
```

Here, you don't need `a[:]` since we're no longer copying the reference (`+` creates and returns a new list anyway).